# Getting a 404 when trying to access my Zend module

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks, module

I'm trying to learn Zend Framework 1.12 module directory structure so I created it by hand. So far I have the modules sort of working with the default by adding this to my Bootstrap.php which resides under my application folder.

```
$this->bootstrap("frontController");  
$front = $this->getResource("frontController");          
$front->addModuleDirectory(APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules');
```

I tried using application.ini to do this with the settings below, but it kept giving me an exception saying 'No default controller directory registered with front controller'.

```
resources.frontController.defaultController = "index"
resources.frontController.defaultAction = "index"
resources.frontController.defaultModule = "default"
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules" 
resources.modules[] = ""
```

Here is my directory structure:

```
root 
|
+- application
   |
   +- configs
   |  |
   |  +- application.ini
   |     
   +- modules
      |
      +- default
      |  |
      |  +- controllers
      |  |  |
      |  |  +- IndexController.php
      |  |
      |  +- views
      |     |
      |     +- scripts
      |        |
      |        +- index
      |           |
      |           +- index.phtml
      |  
      +- signup
         |      
         +- controllers
         |  |
         |  +- IndexController.php
         |
         +- views
            |
            +- scripts
               |
               +- index
                 |
                 +- index.phtml
```

This is my rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^myroot/.*$ index.php [NC]
```

I try accessing http://mysite.com/root/signup but I keep getting 404. Am I missing something to setup modules in Zend?

**Update:**
If I set my default to signup, it works.

```
resources.frontController.defaultModule = "signup"
```

My best guess right now is the RewriteRule is not redirecting it to index.php when I enter

http://www.mysite.com/root/signup

Comment: is /root/ the location of the main index.php script?

Comment: Yes, that is where my main index.php which setups Zend resides.

Comment: just for giggles try going to http://mysite.com/root/signup/index/index

Comment: I actually tried that as well but still get a 404. I'll add my rewrite rule.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `application.ini`

```
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.modules[] = "default"
resources.modules[] = "signup"
```

Comment: If I remove the addModuleDirectory() call from Bootstrap.php and add those lines to my application.ini, it gives me the 'No default controller directory registered with front controller' exception.